# ng-bind-html not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to insert HTML into my div (bottom of code).  I've dealt with an issue like this before so I added a filter.  However, when the div is made visible through a toggle function the HTML doesn't display from the service.  I have verified that the service is returning the proper HTML code.

The div is unhidden but no html is displayed.

Angular Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
    return function (val) {
        if ((typeof val == 'string' || val instanceof String)) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
        }
    };
});




myApp.controller('myAppController', function ($scope, $http) {
... 
SERVICE CODE 
...

$scope.toggleHTMLResults();
$scope.HTMLjson = obj[0].HTML;
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="returnedHTML" ng-bind-html="HTMLjson | unsafe " ng-hide="HTMLResults">NOT HIDDEN</div>
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Here is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tXyRZ0Ze3Y9lJZJO0hpX?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple things wrong with your example.

- Main Javascript file declared twice, first in header and second before close on body tag
- You call a function as `HTMLAPI()` instead of `$scope.HTMLAPI()`
- Your `$scope.HTMLAPI()` function was also being called before it was initialised

Fixed controller code:

```
app.controller('myAppCTRL', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    var API = this;
    $scope.HTMLInput = true;
    $scope.HTMLResults = true;

    $scope.toggleHTMLInput = function () {
        $scope.HTMLInput = $scope.HTMLInput === false ? true : false;
    }

    $scope.toggleHTMLResults = function () {
        $scope.HTMLResults = $scope.HTMLResults === false ? true : false;
    }

    $scope.HTMLAPI = function (HTML) {
          var newJSON = ["[{\"ConditionId\":1111,\"ConditionDescription\":\"<i>DATA GOES HERE</i>\",\"ErrorId\":0,\"DisplayId\":0,\"DisplayName\":\"\",\"ErrorValue\":\"\"}]"];
          var obj = JSON.parse(newJSON);
          $scope.HTMLjson = obj[0].ConditionDescription;
          $scope.toggleHTMLResults();

          console.log($scope.HTMLjson);
    }

    $scope.HTMLAPI();
}]);
```

[**Working Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/8pWztU5zhrGlivnIkJEc?p=preview)

Comment: it appears the version of Angular also had something to do with it.  After I fixed my original example it still wasn't working until I changed the version to 1.5.5

Comment: @webdad3 Glad I could help :)